# Javascript regex to match words separated by a spaced delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex, dojo

I would like to validate an input of words separated by some delimiter.
The delimiter in this case is the "|" sign, separated by space before and after

```
Hello | There | Yes   -----> Match
Hello                 -----> Match
hello|There           -----> No Match
```

So far I've gotten to only the first word with the following rejex:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+
```

how do I separate the words or numbers with a space and a delimiter? 
PS Still working through the tutorials. Any help would be appreciated

To Further clarify, i'm looking for regex for the above for a dojo dijit widget to validate the input properly.

```
    dojo.declare("some.class", dijit.form.ValidationTextBox, {
         regExp: ""

    });

   dojo.addOnLoad(function() {

     var formString = new some.class({
        }, "StringName");
   }

     <form id="myForm" name="myForm">
        String: <input id="StringName" name="name" type="text">
    </form>
```

Comment: That would be the simple way to do it no doubt, but i'm looking for a regex version

Comment: `"Hello | There | Yes".split(' | ').join().split('').indexOf('|') === -1` AND `"Hello| There |Yes".split(' | ').join().split('').indexOf('|') !== -1`

Comment: @Avi did you want to do check for whole line? What would be your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes the whole line as in "Hello | There | Yes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a regex, you can use a simple regex like this:

```
^\w+(?:\s\|\s\w+)*$   <--- this allows a unique word
or
^\w+(?:\s\|\s\w+)+$   <--- this allows two words at least
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/uH3eP9/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Javascript code:

```
var re = /^\w+(?:\s\|\s\w+)*$/gm; 
var str = 'Hello | There | Yes\nhello|There\n456 | 654 | 645 | 465';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know it will always be one space followed by a pipe character followed by one space, it is probably easier to use `split()` without a regexp.

```
var myArray = myString.split(' | ');
```

If you absolutely must use a regexp because (for example) you don't know what kind of whitespace character or how many there will be, you can still use `split()` but just pass it the regexp:

```
var myRegExp = /\s+\|\s+/;
var myArray = myString.split(myRegExp);
```

Comment: prolly better to `/\s*\|\s*/`

Comment: How this would check the whole line?

Comment: @CrayonViolent the OP wants spaces around the pipes, although it's not clear whether multiple spaces, or newlines etc are allowed.  Might be safter to go with `/ | /`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to match the whole line if the line is of above mentioned format.

```
^[A-Za-z\d]+(?:\s\|\s[A-Za-z\d]+)+$
```

**OR**

Use this if you want to match a single word also.

```
^[A-Za-z\d]+(?:\s\|\s[A-Za-z\d]+)*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lM1tP9/2)

```js
var s = "Hello | There | Yes";
var s1 = "hello|There";
var s2 = "456 | 654 | 645 | 465";
alert(/^[A-Za-z\d]+(?:\s\|\s[A-Za-z\d]+)+$/.test(s))
alert(/^[A-Za-z\d]+(?:\s\|\s[A-Za-z\d]+)+$/.test(s1))
alert(/^[A-Za-z\d]+(?:\s\|\s[A-Za-z\d]+)+$/.test(s2))
```